Get parent class in std::type_info map
I might have misunderstand how std::type_info and inheritance works, but when we have:
class A
{
    virtual void x() = 0;
}

class B : public A
{
    virtual void y() = 0;
}

class C : public B
{
    //Implement
}

And a map std::map<std::type_info, std::shared_ptr<A>> m_map, is it possible to get the C instance in this map using m_map.find(std::type_info(B)) ?

Yes you seem to misunderstand the std::type_info type and its uses. But if you ask about the underlying problem you need to solve, the reason you have this map to begin with, and we might be able to help you solve that problem instead. Otherwise this question is an XY problem.

The type std::map<std::type_info, std::shared_ptr<A>> isn't useful - I don't think there's any way to put anything in it. You need instead std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<A>>.

@Someprogrammerdude Well in my case i implement an ECS pattern. The a is the base component, the B is the drawable component and the C is a SpriteDraw component. For the purpose of the Renderer system i want to get the Drawable component (Since this is where the render() virtual method is).

If you insert a pointer to C under std::type_index(std::type_info(B)), then of course you would later extract a pointer to C from the key std::type_index(std::type_info(B)) (or to be precise, a std::shared_ptr<A> pointer that actually points to a C object). If that's what you are asking. It's unclear how you plan to populate your m_map, but in any case, it'll give you back exactly what you've put into it. It's just a container.

I assume you want to get all "B" objects (or objects inheriting from "B") in the map from your example in the question? Then why not a simple vector and a range-based for loop together with std::dynamic_pointer_cast to attempt and downcast the pointer? If the downcast succeed, then you have a "B" object.

type_info is not useful for reflection -- it can't tell you anything about the type it refers to (other than its "name" which is just a string that may be no relation to its actual name in the source).  In particular, there's no way to tell from the type_info if two types are related to each other by inheritance or anything else.
